# Android push notification error in Corona

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, coronasdk

Even by using sample project provided in Corona SDk , I get a notification with error 400. I guess my json data is correct. Following is the code for Json message.

```
local jsonMessage =
[[
    "registration_ids": ["]] .. tostring(googleRegistrationId) .. [["],
    "data":
    {
        "alert": "Hello World!",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}


]]
```

[image: This Error message is encounter everytime]

This is the message on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by changing the format of my json and checking the format on this link  http://jsonlint.com/# . This was a great help and also I replace alert icon by custom icon by using this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 400 error code, the problem must be your JSON :

> 400
>
> Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not
>   be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance,
>   passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure
>   reason is described in the response and the problem should be
>   addressed before the request can be retried.

With all the square brackets and html tag, it's really hard to understand from your question how your JSON actually looks like.

Anyway, here's how it should look like :

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["some reg id"],
    "data":
    {
        "alert": "Hello World!",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , sorry @Eran for that message. I have edited it and the solution you mentioned above doesn't work. It was show some error.